# Consultas mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Cómo obtengo la suma de la columna **total** en la columna **total_factura**. La función `sum` me devuelve el valor en una sola fila.

```
SELECT A.P_NOMBRE,
       A.P_APELLIDO,
       B.FECHA_VENTA,
       A.NIT,
       C.PRECIO AS PRECIO_UNITARIO,
       D.CANTIDAD,
       (C.PRECIO*D.CANTIDAD) AS TOTAL,
       C.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO,
       (C.PRECIO*D.CANTIDAD) AS TOTAL_FACTURA
FROM CLIENTE A, VENTA B, PRODUCTO C, VENTA_DETALLE D
WHERE A.COD_CLIENTE=B.COD_CLIENTE AND C.COD_PRODUCTO=D.COD_PRODUCTO AND NIT=11223344;
```

Comment: Entiendo, soy nuevo aquí. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: ¿Podrías cambiar la imagen por el código de tu sentencia sql por favor?

Comment: He agregado el código, espero tu ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes conseguir lo que buscas haciendo una subconsulta en la sentencia que ya tienes, de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT A.P_NOMBRE,
       A.P_APELLIDO,
       B.FECHA_VENTA,
       A.NIT,
       C.PRECIO AS PRECIO_UNITARIO,
       D.CANTIDAD,
       (C.PRECIO*D.CANTIDAD) AS TOTAL,
       C.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO,
       (SELECT SUM(C2.PRECIO*D2.CANTIDAD) 
       FROM CLIENTE A2, VENTA B2, PRODUCTO C2, VENTA_DETALLE D2
       WHERE A2.COD_CLIENTE=B2.COD_CLIENTE AND C2.COD_PRODUCTO=D2.COD_PRODUCTO AND NIT=11223344) 
       AS TOTAL_FACTURA
FROM CLIENTE A, VENTA B, PRODUCTO C, VENTA_DETALLE D
WHERE A.COD_CLIENTE=B.COD_CLIENTE AND C.COD_PRODUCTO=D.COD_PRODUCTO AND NIT=11223344;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Marc's.